# Django - Is there a way to find the maximum/minimum value of a field from models without using an iterator?

Tags: django

For instance I have a model like so:

```
class Record(models.Model):
     name = CharField(...)
     price = IntegerField(...)
     year = IntegerField(...)
```

How can I find the minimum or maximum of year without using a for, or while iterator?

Answer (score 9):

This [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) is about how aggregation works in Django. For instance, for your `Record` model class you can compute the `min` and `max` value for `price` attribute using the following syntax:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max

Record.objects.annotate(Min("price"), Max("price"))
```